# ЧПУ (URL) для ссылок

Tags: php, html, чпу

У меня есть `index.php, login.php, mypage.php, main.html, rpage.html`. Все события должны происходить на index.php странице, то есть index.php как бы каркас для всего, только вот когда юзер переходит на другие страницы должен быть как-бы не переход по `href`, а подгрузка файла, допустим `mypage.php`. Я хочу сделать типа ЧПУ, то есть index.php главная страница, а все остальные подгружаются к ней, отрабатывают и показывают свои действия. Только вот я не могу так сделать ибо у меня переход по ссылке и нету ЧПУ такого типа `?page=menu или ?page=login`, что мне делать? Как сделать ЧПУ такого типа и подгружать вторичный данные к основной index.php странице?

Comment: Переделывать ссылки

Comment: @ArchDemon подскажите пожалуйста как переделывать? Я в этом полный профан, задал вопрос здесь ибо в интернете ответа не нашел.

Comment: Ну вместо `login.php` пишите в файлах `?page=login`

Comment: @ArchDemon разве оно будет воспринимать это? То есть мне в header("Location") тоже передавать url такого ввида? в include тоже? Вообще понять не могу где что изменять

Comment: в include не нужно, вы же файл подключаете. В `header("Location")` тоже так передавать. Менять нужно в ссылках `<a href="...">` и формах `<form action="...">`

Comment: @ArchDemon так я все равно не пойму, в href нужно указывать существующую html страницу, я не могу казать что попало если я сделаю так `<a href="?page=login">` у меня ничего не заработает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82089/discussion-between-archdemon-and-tramway).